# Connecting a mobile device to IOT system in a home

Tags: mobile, architecture, embedded, cloud, iot

I am interested in building a device that will be connected to my home network and I will be able to control remotely via an app on my cell phone.

My original thought is this:

- Both systems will pull data from some cloud service
- My mobile device will modify a data entry in the cloud service
- The device will be constantly pulling this data and update the necessary setting when they change

Concerns with the original thought:

- Constant pulling of the device in order to see when data has been changed (inefficient)
- No way to communicate from the device to the phone (feature limiting)

**Question:**

- **What is the best way to create the link between my mobile device and the device that will remain in my home?**

*Potential similar architectures include Nest, Ring, etc.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept is correct - typically, IoT devices and mobile apps communicate through the cloud. There are cases when you want to connect your app directly to a device (e.g. through bluetooth, LAN or sometimes even internets), but that is done usually for a specific reason, e.g.:

- IP cameras generate a lot of traffic, putting it through a centralized server is very expensive, so cheap home products do P2P from mobile app (centralized served could help you get the IP address for your camera)
- TV with phone as remote control. Using cloud service hear would be weird and limiting access to LAN simplifies the setup

In general cases (Next, Ring) you can be pretty sure the IoT devices talk to the cloud, instead of the mobile app directly. It both offer more feature (as the data can be processed in bulk in cloud), but there's also benefits for using the cloud even if it's  used only to relay data.

In many cases, you also want to limit traffic (e.g. save batteries or data plan). Two key aspects to be able to do that:

- Don't waste time setting up a connection. That means connecting to a stable cloud service (your mobile might not be online) and using optimized network (e.g. LAN with static IP address, NB-IoT or LTE-M)
- Choose optimal M2M protocol. Two popular M2M protocols are COAP ("light weight HTTP") and MQTT (a messaging protocol)

Once you've set up how both your device and mobile app can exchange data with the server, it's up to you to design how to use that. Note that there's nothing stopping from the device to also push data to the server - all connection (IoT device <-> cloud <-> mobile app) can use two-way protocols.

Comment: Wow thank you very much for the detailed response. Follow up question: What do you mean by p2p in your first bullet? Can you elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: P2P = peer to peer (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer)

For consumer grade IP cameras, you would typically get the IP address for your camera to access the video feed directly in the browser or mobile app. I've seen 2 approaches:
1) you need to set up IP address manually
2) the camera connects to cloud service, which sets up a unique domain name for your camera (e.g. [unique-ID].[brand].com)